# onclick in a checkbox doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make an event handler onclick and IE 9,8,7 event starts work only when I turn on the console when I turn it off will work too. How can I solve this problem? Thank you!
There is my code:

```
function changeCheck(id) // onClick функция акт/деакт. checkbox
{
    //checkbox = $('span#'+id).children().eq(0); // получаем checkbox в объект
    checkbox = $('span#'+id).children().eq(0); // получаем checkbox в объект
    console.log(checkbox);
    if(checkbox.attr('rel') !='nosumm') 
    {
        var totalSum = parseInt($('div#stoim').children().text()); // получаем начальную стоимость        
        if(!checkbox.attr('value').length) // если кликнули по "платежным системам" 
        {
            if((checkbox).is(':checked') == false) // если еще не отмечено, то отмечаем
            {
                checkbox.checked=true;
                $('span#'+id).css('background-position','0 -22px');
                if(checkbox.attr('checked','checked'))
                {
                    $('div#type_plati').slideDown();
                }
            }
            else // если checkbox отмечен
            {
                $('span#'+id).css('background-position','0 0');
        for(var key in paysystem)
        {
                    if($('input#choise'+paysystem[key]).attr('value') && $('input#choise'+paysystem[key]).is(':checked')==true)
                    {
            //console.log($('input#choise'+paysystem[key]).attr('value'));
            //console.log($('input#choise'+paysystem[key]).is(':checked'));
            totalSum = totalSum - parseInt($('input#choise'+paysystem[key]).attr('value'));         
                    }
                    $('span#niceCheckbox'+paysystem[key]).css('background-position','0 0');
                    $('span#niceCheckbox'+paysystem[key]).children().eq(0).removeAttr('checked');
                }
                $('input#subTotal').val(totalSum); // Записуем финальную цену на отправку
                $('div#stoim').children().text(totalSum);           
                if(checkbox.removeAttr('checked')) $('div#type_plati').slideUp(); 
            }        
        }
        else
        {
            if((checkbox).is(':checked') == false) // если еще не отмечено, то отмечаем
            {
                checkbox.checked=true;
                $('span#'+id).css('background-position','0 -22px');
                checkbox.attr('checked','checked');
                if(checkbox.attr('checked','checked'))
                {
                    totalSum = totalSum + parseInt($(checkbox).attr('value'));
                    $('div#stoim').children().text(totalSum);
                }
            }
            else // если checkbox отмечен
            {
                $('span#'+id).css('background-position','0 0');
                if(checkbox.removeAttr('checked'))
                {
                    totalSum = totalSum - parseInt($(checkbox).attr('value'));
                    $('div#stoim').children().text(totalSum);
                }
             } 
            $('input#subTotal').val(totalSum); // Записуем финальную цену на отправку
            $('div#stoim').children().text(totalSum);           
        }
    }
    else // обычные checkbox
    {
        if((checkbox).is(':checked') == false) // если еще не отмечено, то отмечаем
        {
            checkbox.checked=true;
            $('span#'+id).css('background-position','0 -22px');
            checkbox.attr('checked','checked');
        }
        else // если checkbox отмечен
        {
            $('span#'+id).css('background-position','0 0');
            checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
        }  
    }    

}
```

There is html code:

```
<li><span class="niceCheck"  onclick="changeCheck(this.id)" id="niceCheckbox2" rel=""><input type="checkbox" name="ch1" id="ch1" value="370"/> <label  for="ch1">Форма обратной связи</label></span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `console.log(checkbox);` in your code thats not commented out.
This will break the code in IE if there is no console.

And since you're already using jQuery you might want to take a look at the `.change()` function/event in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/change/
This could be what you want to use in the first place.

Comment: @Nait87 If that solved your problem, you [might want to consider accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is of course completely voluntary and there is no obligation to do so. It just lets us know this answer was helpful to you and that your problem has been solved. (Besides resulting in a small bonus for the person who answered).